# Alloy 4, Software Abstractions 2E, and the seq keyword

Tags: alloy

Not long ago I acquired the second edition of *Software Abstractions*, and when I needed to refresh my memory on how to spell the name of the `elems` function I thought "Oh, good, I can check the new edition instead of trying to read my illegible handwritten notes in the end-papers of the first edition."

But I can't find "seq" or "elems" or the names of any of the other helper functions in the index, nor do I see any mention of the `seq` keyword in the language reference in Appendix B.

One or more of the following seems likely to be the case; which?

- I am missing something.  (What? where?)
- The `seq` keyword is not covered in Appendix B because it's not strictly speaking a keyword in the way that `set` and the other unary operators are.  (Please expound!)
- The support for sequences was added to Alloy 4 after the second edition went to press, and so the book needs to be augmented by reference to the discussion of new features in Alloy 4 in the [Quick Guide](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/index.html) and the [Alloy 4 grammar](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/alloy4-grammar.txt) on the Web site. (Ah, OK.  Pages are slow, bits are fast.)
- Other ...

I guess, to try to put a generally useful question here, that I'm asking:  what exactly is the relation between the language implemented by the Alloy Analyzer 4.2 (or any 4.*) and the language defined in *Software abstractions* second edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation corresponds to [this](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/seq.html) online documentation.

Sequences are really not part of the language; `x: seq A` can be seen just as a syntactic sugar for `x: Int -> A`, and all the utility functions (e.g., `first`, `last`, `elems`) are library-defined (in `util/sequence`).  The actual implementation is a little more complicated (just so that we can let the user write something like `x.elems` and make the type checker happy at the same time), but conceptually that's what's going on.